# Shortest way to print the first 20 numbers in the fibbonacci sequence with python3

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

I was wondering if it was possible to make this code even shorter than it already was.

```
f=lambda x:f(x-1)+f(x-2) if x>1 else 1
[print(f(i))for i in range(20)]
```

Expected output:

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
```

Good luck, "golfers" (I'm assuming thats what you guys are called)

Note: specifically in Python 3
Note2: By shortest I mean taking up the least characters

Comment: On [https://code.golf/fibonacci#python](https://code.golf/fibonacci#python) (printing the first 30 starting with 0), the best Python 3 answers are 36 bytes, so there's quite a bit of room for golfing. for a starting point, take a look at our [Python golf tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/20260).